# Laravel controller does not pass data from validate variable. Problem with the 'address' field in the database table

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, migration, laravel-10

I'm creating User. Which has too much fields for adding user I break them in to steps and make 4 pages and handle them in Usercontroller. But in 1st step (1st page) when i save data it give me error which means Address value is missing but in dd() address value is shown
error i get is following
[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD86I.png)

I also share migration as follow:

```
   `  $table->id();
           $table->string('photo', 5120)->nullable();
           $table->string('emp_code')->unique();
           $table->string('designation');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('username')->unique();
           $table->string('password'); // Added password column
           $table->string('father_name');
           $table->string('mother_name');
           $table->string('marital_status');
           $table->string('spouse_name')->nullable();
           $table->string('address');
           $table->date('date_of_birth');
           $table->string('place_of_birth');
           $table->string('gender');
           $table->string('religion');
           $table->string('cnic_no');
           $table->string('family_code');
           $table->string('ntn_no')->nullable();
           $table->string('blood_group')->nullable();
           $table->string('phone_no')->unique();
           $table->string('home_phone_no')->nullable();
           $table->string('email')->unique();
           $table->string('website')->nullable();
           $table->string('kin_name')->nullable();
           $table->string('kin_contact_no')->nullable();
           $table->string('kin_cnic')->unique()->nullable();
           $table->string('relationship')->nullable();
           $table->rememberToken();
           $table->timestamps();
```

Following is controller function of that page

```
     public function storeUserDetails(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'photo' => 'nullable|file|max:5120', // Validate photo file and limit size to 5MB
            'emp_code' => 'required|unique:users,emp_code',
            'designation' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
            'password' => 'required',
            'father_name' => 'required',
            'mother_name' => 'required',
            'marital_status' => 'required',
            'spouse_name' => 'nullable',
            'address' => 'required',
        ]);
//dd($validatedData);
        // Upload and store the photo if provided
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $photoPath = $request->file('photo')->store('photos');
            $validatedData['photo'] = $photoPath;
        }

        // Create a new user with the validated data
        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        // Store the user ID in the session for future steps
        session(['user_id' => $user->id]);

        return redirect()->route('user.identity');
    }
```

What should I do?

I'm creating User. Which has too much fields for adding user I break them in to steps and make 4 pages and handle them in Usercontroller. In First step function is storeUserDetails(). I want that my data is save in session and move to next step one by one and complete adding user in system.

Comment: Do not post code as images. **Code is text** and can be copied, pasted and otherwise manipulated. **Images are static** and cannot. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76255497/edit) and include your code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Share your blade file code where you're passing address

Answer (score 2):

It seems the address field is missing in the fillable section in your model

check the User Model, confirm 'address' is in the fillable properties

`protected $fillable = ['photo', 'address' ...]`